# Not able to receive SMS_RECEIVED listener in 2.3.6

Tags: android

I have implemented `SMS_RECEIVED` listener in app. Its working in android 2.2 but not in 2.3.7.

Is there any compatibility issue with android 2.3.7.

My code is

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
      Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
      SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
      // String msg_from;
      if (bundle != null) {
        try {
          Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
          msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
          for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            // msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
            Toast.makeText(context, msgBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Also I have added respective entries in manifest file as :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Help appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: not sure, but instead of this line `if (intent.getAction().equals(Utils.SMSBROADCAST))` try this code `if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"))`

Comment: actually `Utils.SMSBROADCAST = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"`. I have accessed it from my Utils class

Comment: did you declared the receiver in the manifest?

Comment: its not working in 2.3.7. same problem.

Comment: can you post your AndroidManifest.xml file?